# Android, problems with importing jars

Tags: android, jar

I import jars to my project as follows:

1- copy the jar to /libs

2- right click on the jar > add to build path.

The problem is that I get "method is not defined" and "var cannot be resolved or is not a field".

I used [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) to see the source code, and found that the var and the methods are there. what can be causing this problem ?

Comment: Are you importing the required class files in the classes you wish to use them?

Comment: Make sure you check the "export" checkbox on the JAR in the build path.

Comment: @AleksG Actually I do.

Comment: Have you checked that if is it available in Android Java Build path???

Comment: @PiyushGupta I added it to the build path

Comment: So its gives a error to that jar file with red mark in that build path?

Comment: @PiyushGupta no, it's not showing red marks.

Comment: So just when run your application its gives "method is not defined" and "var cannot be resolved or is not a field"???

Comment: @PiyushGupta it doesn't build ... it shows errors in the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check if the JAR file you want to reference is only being referenced once? Sometimes it may happen that in the Build Path you can see that the JAR file is present in the Android Private Libraries and also been added externally.

Comment: in such case, what should I do?? if removed from the libraries/dependencies it'll generate errors in the library ptoject.

Comment: Just copy the JAR in the libs folder. Rest would be taken care of.